# Make a hyperlink change color after click

Tags: beamer, hyperref, pdf, hyperlink

Is there a way for hyperlinks (in a Beamer presentation) to change color after click? (Similarly to MS Word, Powerpoint browsers etc.)

(I need it for a kind of Jeopardy game where the questions should disappear after being played.)

Comment: Check out the eforms package for \pushButton, \AS and \Fhidden.

Comment: Also check out the `jeapordy` package and `jj_game` class.

Comment: @Dan, jj_game seems to be the package I'm looking for, thanks!